# How does console.log work?

Tags: javascript, console, logging

#### First Example:

In the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ScTAW/4/
I have this js:

```
var storage = (function () {
    var store = [];
    return {
        "add": function (item) {
            store.push(item);
        },
        "get": function () {
            return store;
        }
    };
}());

storage.add('hi there')
console.log(storage, storage.get(), storage.add('hi there #2'));
```

And here is what gets printed to the console:

> Object
>    ["hi there", "hi there #2"] undefined

One would think that the console should only say:

> Object
>    ["hi there"] undefined

becase the second push did **not** happen until after the value was logged, therefore it should not be displayed.

---

#### Second Example:

In the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ScTAW/5/

I am using the same `storage` variable but I log like so:

```
storage.add('hi there')
console.log(storage, storage.get(), (function() {
    storage.add('hi there #2');
    console.log('TESTING');
})());
```

What gets printed to the console is:

> TESTING
>   Object
>    ["hi there", "hi there #2"] undefined

hmmmm well that is odd now isnt it? One could expect to see:

> Object
>    ["hi there"] undefined
>   TESTING

Why is this happening? What is going on behind the scenes of the console logging mechanism?

Comment: I came across an interesting blog post about this: http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that all parameters in the log method must be evaluated right to left because parameters to the left can contain data from parameters on the right.

Comment: @Jaimie -- ok, but my question is '**WHY?**' most languages go left-right, not right-left

Comment: @Jamie Dixon: I find that hard to believe, Method arguments are not like operators. Do you have any backing example?

Comment: If we have a look at the API for Firebugs console.log we see the use of %s in the first parameter. This is merging the data from paramters on the right into the one on the left. http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.log.28object.5B.2C_object.2C_....5D.29

Comment: Consider another example in C# Console.Write("Hello {0}", foo());. The method foo() must evaluate before the first string can be fully evaluated. In this example foo() returns a string "World".

Comment: @Jaimie -- this isnt c#... and idk what that is supposed to do...

Comment: I know this isn't C# I'm just pointing out an example of another language doing something similar.

Comment: The answer to Why has to be "Because it has to". In order that string substitution be done on the left, the methods on the right need to fire. There may be other ways they could do this however this seems like the simplest way, gather the pieces then put them together.

Comment: @Jamie, I wonder why you think that parameter evaluation from left to right or the other way around would change how that C# expression would work...

Comment: @Jamie: `Console.Write("Hello {0}", foo());` is not the same. The first argument is the `format string` which _expects_ other arguments. `console.log` has no such equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean @Blindy? If in the example I gave, the method foo() was not evaluated before the string, how would the Write method know to substitute {0} with "World"?

Comment: @JamieDixon to quote an old saying: `C# is to javascript as car is carpet` :-P

Comment: @Mrchief. console.log does expect other arguments. According to the API we can do soemthing almost exactly the same. console.log("I am %s", function(){return "Jamie"});

Comment: @Jamie: Again, _that_ call is not the _same_ as the one in OP's post.

Comment: @Jamie, who cares if `foo()` or `"Hello {0}"` gets evaluated first? Once you're *inside* `Console.Write`, they're both evaluated regardless.

Comment: @Jamie -- that shows `I am function (){return "Jamie"}` in the log....

Comment: @Blindy -- yes, but in what order?

Comment: My previous example was a bad one :) So much for untested code. The sample in the API is a better example and it works. console.log("The %s jumped over %d tall buildings", "dog", 5);

Comment: @Neal, nobody sane cares... You're the kind of person who asks what the result of `i++ + ++i` is then gets into a (really long) argument about how he'd *expect* it to be different...

Comment: @Blindy I think the OP cares. That's the question I was answering.

Comment: @Neal **I know** the diff between post and pre incrementing -- this is nothing like it.

Comment: @Jamie, then you chose the wrong example, because in that one (as is the case with your `console.log("The %s jumped over %d tall buildings", "dog", 5)` it doesn't matter what order they're in. You seem to think that because *semantically* the format depends on the parameters (or the other way around?), the order they're read in matters. It doesn't though, they're all just *independent strings* getting passed to a function.

Comment: The only place where the order the parameters are evaluated in are pathological cases like `i++ + ++i` or the OP's example, where you're both *reading* and *writing* to *the same location in memory* in *the same instruction*.

Comment: I hear you @Blindy. I'm making the assumption that if the first parameter needs data from a second parameter (such as in the case where the second parameter is a method returning a string), that the second parameter must evaluate at least before the first parameter is completely evaluated. I may be completely off the mark with that.

Comment: In javascript, the parameters to functions are evaluated from left to right, then passed to the function. If one of the parameters on the right modifies an object that is involved on the left, the function will get the object in it's modified state because it is a reference. There isn't any distinction between which parameter "needs" which other parameter.

Comment: Blindy is totally right. What matters is that any function that is passed as an argument will be evaluated before `console.lorg` is called. In none of the examples the evaluation order amongst the arguments themselves matters. An example where it would is this:
`console.log(++i, i)`.

Comment: `console.log` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In most (if not all) imperative programming languages, any arguments passed to a function call have to be evaluated before the function can be called (so called [Eager evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation)). Also, they are in general evaluated in order from left to right (for C for instance it's undefined), however in both examples the order in which the arguments are evaluated does not matter. This should be pretty obvious when looking at what happens in detail:

As mentioned, before `console.log` can be called, `storage.get()` has to be executed first, returning the `store` array. Then `storage.add('hi there #2')` will be executed (or the other way round), so its result (in this case `undefined`, since `add` does not return anything) can be passed as the third argument to `console.log`. This means that the once `console.log` will be called with the arguments `(storage, storage.store, undefined)`, the `store` array already contains "hi there #2", hence producing the results you observe.

In the second example the reasoning is again the same, the function call is just a bit more obscured. On first look it looks there is a function passed as a 3rd argument to the `console.log` function; but it's actually a function call (observer the `()` at the end). So `storage.add('hi there #2')` will be executed, then `console.log('TESTING')` and then the `undefined` result from the anonymous function execution will be again passed to `console.log`.

If you did actually pass a function to `console.log`, it would print that function definition, and not execute anything. So:

```
storage.add('hi there')
console.log(storage, storage.get(), (function() {
    storage.add('hi there #2');
    console.log('TESTING');
}));
```

, without the `()` at the end, results in:

```
Object
 ["hi there"] function () {
    storage.add('hi there #2');
    console.log('TESTING');
}
```

I hope this makes things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

When you're calling `console.log` like this

```
console.log(storage, storage.get(), storage.add('hi there #2'));
```

`storage.add('hi there #2')` is evaluated and the ***return value*** is passed to `console.log`. Evaluating it causes the array item to be added to `store` immediately.

Same thing with `storage.get()` -> `store`. So effectively, the statement becomes:

```
console.log(storage, store, [return value of add which is undefined]);
```

When it prints, `store` is evaluated and its content are output which is why you see `["hi there", "hi there #2"]`

---

In your second example also, the anonymous function is evaluated first and the results are passed on.

Comment: It's the same, your inner function gets evaluated first.

Comment: @Blindy: Thanks. I was about to add that to my answer.

Comment: See my comment to @Blindy's answer.

Comment: @Neal: and blindy's comment says it all. You're not passing a reference. You're passing the result of an evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

All arguments to `console.log` will first be iterated and evaluated in order to assemble the output. As it is iterating the arguments you've passed, changes are made to objects and functions are called. **After** the logger has iterated the arguments, it outputs the data.

Because objects are byRef, your "second argument" changes to the `storage.store` object are reflected in the console output. Because the arguments are iterated, the function call in your last argument is called *before* the output is assembled, so you see the output from your function call before you see the output of the first `console.log` call.

It is worth noting, then, that the output of `console.log` is not going to show you objects as they exist at the time of the call to `console.log`. What you actually get, in the case of objects, is a reference handle to the object. Thus, any changes to the object made after the handle has been added to `console.log`'s output will still be reflected in the object itself. Since the handle only points to the object itself, you are not getting output showing the state of the object as it was when you called the function, but rather a live link to the object as it is *now*.

Answer (score 1):

Your storage adding function is completely evaluated *before* `console.log` *is called* because it's a parameter.

This is not specific to `console.log`, this is how every imperative programming language works.

Comment: When params are passed it is usually **not** by reference, unless you tell it to. therefore the 2nd param should remain the same.

Comment: All objects are byRef in js. Primitives are byVal.

Comment: What's your point? The function still gets evaluated and the return value still gets passed down to `console.log`. There is literally nothing magic happening here, it's the same as `console.log(gettime())` if you had a function that returned the current time as a string.

Comment: @Blindy -- yes, but would u expenct for your function to be volatile like: `console.log(gettime(), setTime('+1 days'))` and it would display the next day as the log, even though you wanted to see the current day???

Comment: Yes, I would. What you *want* doesn't matter, only your ability to express yourself clearly does.

Comment: @Neal, then I suggest either reading a book on the internals of how functions get called (for example, books on Assembler or compiler design explain this), or simply taking our word for it.

Comment: @Blindy complilers??? javascript dont need no stinking compilers (lol), but seriously, js is a script, it goes from top to bottom, there is no reason why something in the right should affect something before it.

Comment: Noted; you're wrong. If you don't care about why, then don't ask why.

Comment: Agree with @Blindy, every answer here explains the concept in a slightly different way. You've been answered, but you seem to reject the facts for some reason.

Comment: @Blindly: I downvoted you because it is not how every programming language works. For instance Haskell does not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation. I think if you wrote "how every *imperative* programming language works" it would be fine, but I would not even be 100% sure on that - there might be some obscure one out there that does not.